# What's the best way to convert a date and time into a timestamp using php?

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

I need to convert a date and time (GMT) into a timestamp with php. The following code shows what I'm currently using:

```
<?php
$date="2012-06-29 10:50";
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
echo $timestamp;
?>
```

However, when I test the timestamp in an online convertor (http://www.epochconverter.com), the resulting date is 29th June 2012, 8:50 GMT, or 2 hours previous. Is it possible that the strtotime() function isn't completely accurate and is just an estimate of the time? If so, are there better methods I could use for getting the exact time?

Thanks.

Comment: it is time of the server, if you dont share the same time zone with server ie your server is in europe and your are not in europe then you will different time generated, i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime` assumes that you are converting a string in your server's local time, so if the servers time zone is two hours out the result will be as wll.

The comments in [the manual](http://php.net/strtotime) suggest a couple of solutions, you can append UTC to your date:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date.' UTC');
```

Or you can change the default timezone for the script (this will apply to all other time functions!):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

As a final alternative, you could try [`date_create_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) which allows you to specify what exactly the format your string is:

```
$datetime = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i', $date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

$timestamp = date_format($datetime, 'U');
// Alternatively (thanks Herbert) - 5.3+ only
$timestamp = date_timestamp_get($datetime);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information incarnate. I wasn't taking into account it was being converted into my server's local time.